# Algorithm to layout calendar items

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, sorting, calendar

I've been working on a calendar as shown below, and am looking for an algorithm to workout the y/top of the colored bars so that the least amount of vertical space is used.

The image below shows what I have so far, which simply puts each cell below it's predecessor. As you can see the yellow bars could/should sit on the same row.

The data coming is not sorted in any way, and the duration property can vary.

I'm using JavaScript, but appreciate any ideas/pseudo code to help me on my way.

[image]

```
data = [
  {
    name: 'Task One',
    i: [
      {
        id: '1',
        start: '2018-03-13T08:00:00',
        duration: 3600000,
        state: 'warning'
      },
      {
        id: '2',
        start: '2018-03-13T08:30:00',
        duration: 3600000,
        state: 'success'
      },
      {
        id: '3',
        start: '2018-03-13T08:45:00',
        duration: 3600000,
        state: 'success'
      },
      {
        id: '4',
        start: '2018-03-13T09:00:00',
        duration: 3600000,
        state: 'warning'
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might set you on the right track:

```
var tasksOverlap = ( task, task2 ) => {
    return (
        task.start > task2.start + task2.duration ||
        task.start + task.duration < task2.start
    )
}

var rows = [];
tasks.forEach( task => {
    var row = rows.find( row => {
        return !row.some( task2 => tasksOverlap( task, task2 ) )
    })
    if ( row === undefined ) {
        row = [];
        rows.push( row );
    }
    row.push( task );
})
```

Comment: Brilliant.  Thanks very much Ben.